# Adding class to sub element on mouseenter, the class is also added to parent element in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to add a class to an li element which is sub element of an li.

```
<div id="test" class="list">
<ul>
  <li><a id="Inbox">Inbox</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
<li><a id="Sent">Sent</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
<li><a id="Archive">Archive</a>
    <ul></ul>
  </li>
<li><a id="Deleted">Deleted</a>
  <ul>
      <li><a id="Subfolder1">Sub Folder 1</a></li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Mouse enter and Mouse leave functions:

```
$('#test li').each(function(){
    $(this).on("mouseenter",function(){
      $(this).addClass("enter-folder");
    });
    $(this).on("mouseleave",function(){
      $(this).removeClass("enter-folder");
    });
  });
```

When mouse is on subfolder1 the class is adding to subfolder1 li elemnt as well as the parent li element which has text deleted.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/36/

I just want to add class to subfolder1 when mouse is on subfolder1.

How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**event.stopPropagation**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#test li').each(function(){
        $(this).on("mouseenter",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); //added here
          $(this).addClass("enter-folder");
        });
        $(this).on("mouseleave",function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); //added here
          $(this).removeClass("enter-folder");
        });
      });
});
```

**Updated after OP's comment**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/45/)

Use [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var li = $('#test li');
    li.hover(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //added here
        li.removeClass("enter-folder")//added here to remove class from all li items
        $(this).addClass("enter-folder");
    }, function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation(); //added here
        li.removeClass("enter-folder");//added here to remove class from all li items
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not constant: http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/39/. When i directly point mouse on subfolder1 it is adding class to only subfolder one. But when mouse is on deleted and then on subfolder1 then "enter-folder" class is showing on both deleted and for subfolder li elements

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#test li').hover(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
          $('#test li').removeClass("enter-folder");
           $(this).addClass("enter-folder");
        },function(e){
            e.stopPropagation(); 
          $(this).removeClass("enter-folder");
        });
});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/43/)**
reference [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Comment: It is not constant: http://jsfiddle.net/UVJgF/42/. When i directly point mouse on subfolder1 it is adding class to only subfolder one. But when mouse is on deleted and then on subfolder1 then "enter-folder" class is showing on both deleted and for subfolder li elements

Comment: Not working. When my cursor is on subfolder1 and then on delete, "enter-folder" class is not added to "Delete" li element

Comment: you say I just want to add class to subfolder1 when mouse is on subfolder1.  and its working